# Why is my csv data not showing after DUMP command in Apache Pig?

Tags: csv, apache-pig

I'm new to Pig and have the following problem. I'm trying to load a small csv file (10 rows & 22 columns of data),  in Pig using `CSVLoader`, and display the values of 4 of those columns through the DUMP command.
The code I'm using is as follows:

```
grunt>A = LOAD ’/vagrant/test.csv’ USING CSVLoader(’,’) AS (Id:int, PostTypeId:int, AcceptedAnswerId:int, ParentId:int, CreationDate:datetime, DeletionDate:datetime, Score:int, ViewCount:int, Body:chararray, OwnerUserId:int, OwnerDisplayName:chararray, LastEditorUserId:int, LastEditorDisplayName: chararray, LastEditDate:datetime, LastActivityDate:datetime, Title:chararray, Tags:chararray, AnswerCount:int, CommentCount:int, FavoriteCount:int, ClosedDate:chararray);

grunt>B = FOREACH A GENERATE Id,PostTypeId, OwnerUserId,Title;
grunt>DUMP B;
```

I am getting the first two items returned (`Id` and `PostTypeId`), but the other two items are null. For example, a row could show as *"(2003505,1,,)"* And I'm getting multiple lines in my DUMP output showing just *"(,,,,)*, i.e. completely null. So despite expecting just 10 rows in the DUMP output, I'm actually getting 117 rows, most of which are just null values! Snippet below.

Sample output code from the DUMP function:

[image]

I've checked the schema versus the input data and can't see any mismatches as regards character types.

Q1. In the output rows where I get some of the data but not all (*"(2003505,1,,)"*) - why am I missing data?
Q2. And why are there multiple rows showing just "(,,,)"?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Naming the fields is optional, so I would start with not doing that, and generating `$0, $1`, for example. If there are only 10 rows, please add your file to the question

Comment: Thanks for your help, @cricket_007. I actually got it working by going a slightly different route. I saved the file as _.txt_ rather than _.csv_, then cleaned it in Cygwin terminal as follows: 'tr -d '\n' < total.txt > totalClean.txt'. When I loaded the _.txt_ file in Pig using _PigStorage()_, I got the expected output.

Comment: Pig doesn't care about file extensions, by the way